# terminal giving prefix : To-be-filled-by-O-E-M

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, console

Ubuntu 12.04.5
terminal looking like : maxim@maxim-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ 
how remove -To-be-filled-by-O-E-M ?
This happen after Ubuntu reinstall.
Screenshot : [image]

Comment: I don't want to sound too cocky but I think that's a suffix not prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's part of your prompt.  Try:

```
PS1='\$ '
```

Put it in your .bashrc to make the change persist across a reboot.  Or try:

```
PS1='\u@\h\$ '
```

Comment: it helped, but now i not see user, just $ in terminal and I dont know, when running root or not ?

Comment: If you are root, the `$` will become a `#`.  If you add the `\u` and `\h` you will get user name and host.   Your prompt can be greatly customized, and is documented in the bash man page.

Comment: this only beats the symptoms of the acutal problem that your machine is named with that strange name.

Answer (score 3):

found problem:
rename host in /etc/hosts : 127.0.1.1   maxim-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M to maxim
and essential - rename hostname in file /etc/hostname from maxim-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M to maxim for example